# Background color column CSS

Tags: css, background-color

I have 2 columns and a footer. One of the columns is much smaller in content than the other, but I need them to match so both of their background colors run all the way to the footer. It isn't a problem for the larger one, but not the other.

```css
.links {
    background:#55C5E8;
    padding:1em 2.5%;
    width: 30%;
    float: left; 
}
.rechts {
    background:#FD6943;
    padding:1em 2.5%;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
.cf {
    clear:both
}
/*clearfix hack*/
.clearfix::before,
.clearfix::after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix::after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="midden clearfix">
    <div class="rechts">
      <div class="sectie" id="topmodel">
        <h2>ColumnA</h2>
        <p><img src="img/ColumnA.jpg" />ColumnAtext</p>
        <p>ColumnA Text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">linkA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">linkB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">linkC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">linkD</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer cf">
    <p>Footertext</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the midden container a flexbox container

```
.midden { display: flex;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either flex the `midden` div. OR, if you want to preserve your HTML structure, you can set fixed heights on both of your children. See the CSS changes I made below.

```css
.links {
    background:#55C5E8;
    padding:1em 2.5%;
    width: 30%;
    float: right; 
    height: 150px;
}
.rechts {
    background:#FD6943;
    padding:1em 2.5%;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
}
.cf {
    clear:both
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="midden clearfix">
    <div class="rechts">
      <div class="sectie" id="topmodel">
        <h2>ColumnA</h2>
        <p><img src="img/ColumnA.jpg" />ColumnAtext</p>
        <p>ColumnA Text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">linkA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">linkB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">linkC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">linkD</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="footer cf">
    <p>Footertext</p>
  </div>
```